# Debug assertion on Closing of Application

Tags: .net, debugging, visual-c++, mfc, assert

I am getting the following debug assertion on closing of the application :

[image]
I have debugged the flow and found that the assertion is happening in CWnd::DestroyWindow()

```
// Should have been detached by OnNcDestroy
#ifdef _DEBUG
            ASSERT(pMap->LookupPermanent(hWndOrig) == NULL);
```

My class is derived from COleControl which in turn is derived from CWnd.

The object creation is happening in .NET winform and on Closing of application the object destructor is getting called and the assert is coming.

Things I have tried :

1) Calling DestroyWindow() on my class destructor : didnt work

2) Overridden OnFinalRelease like below and it worked :

```
void CSimple::OnFinalRelease()
{
    if (!m_bFinalReleaseCalled)
    {
        m_bFinalReleaseCalled = TRUE;

        ReleaseCaches();

        CWnd::OnNcDestroy(); --> explicitly called OnNcDestroy()

        if (m_hWnd != NULL)
            DestroyWindow();

        CCmdTarget::OnFinalRelease();
    }
```

I am not sure whether this is proper fix. I am also not sure whether the issue is in .NET side.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `CWnd::OnNcDestroy()` from other functions is wrong. Generally, these functions are meant to respond to window messages. In this case, when your window is destroyed, the system will send `WM_NCDESTROY` message (this will be the last message before window is completely destroyed)

You can add `ON_WM_NCDESTROY` to your window message map. And add this function:

```
void CMyWnd::OnNcDestroy() 
{
    CWnd::OnNcDestroy(); 
    ... do other cleanup
}
```

In this case, you might try instead:

```
void CSimple::OnFinalRelease()
{
    if (m_hWnd != NULL)
        DestroyWindow();
    else
        PostNcDestroy(); // add this
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should never call `OnNcDestroy` before you destroy the window. You should never call this handler by yourself. It is a message only called internally from Windows.

`OnNcDestroy` is always called when `DestroyWindow` is called. `OnNcDestroy` is the handler of the `WM_NCDESTROY` message and it is the last message a window receives. This function always call `PostNCDestroy`, that finally removes the window handle from the internal handle maps.

The call to `DesroyWindow` must fail in this sequence...